# Does anyone have better maps for the east coast of the USA, or the entire USA to use with XASTIR directly?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa

I have a fresh install of XASTIR running on a Pi 3, but the maps are pretty poor at showing details. Does anyone have any mapps they can share with me for my XASTIR system, that are better than what the program comes with?  I would like the USA, or the eastern side of the USA. I run an aprs system in Florida, so even Florida would be great.

73'   Joe KQ4BX

Comment: Did you read their "Where to get Maps for Xastir on their site ?

Comment: I barely know what XASTIR is, but can you use openstreetmaps maps or am I missing something important here/

Comment: Here's the link to the page @PROBERT mentioned: https://xastir.org/index.php/Xastir_Maps. It has a list of data sources.